# Direcciones URL para abrir en un mapa un lugar o punto geográfico con su marcador

Tags: html, google-maps

estoy intentando abrir en otra pestaña una ubicación en google maps a partir de unas coordenadas que ya tengo en mi base de datos. Utilicé el siguiente código:

```
<a href="https://maps.google.com/?ll=19.10711285128303,-98.27150480793455&z=20" target="_blank"><img height="25px" src="img/google-maps.png"/></a>
```

El detalle es que no me sale ningún marcador o pin, como puedo hacer que salga un marcador en las coordenadas que especifique?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<!-TABLA DE SOLICITUDES DE INMUEBLE ->
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <button style="width: 90%; text-align: left; background: none; border: none; outline: none;" data-toggle="collapse" href="#Soli_inm">Solicitudes de Inmueble</button><button style="outline: none;" type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" data-toggle="collapse" href="#Soli_inm"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="Soli_inm" class="panel-collapse collapse in"><!--collapse in para que se muestre abierto-->
        <div class="panel-body">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-striped dt-responsive dataTabla2" width="100%">

            <thead>
              <tr style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center;" >
                <td style="width:10px">#</td>
                <td>Inmueble</td>
                <td>Solicitante</td>
                <td>Acciones</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              <?php 
                $contador3 = 0;
                foreach ($MisSolicitudes as $solicitud) {
                  $contador3 = $contador3 + 1;
              ?>
              <tr style="text-align:center;" >
                <td><?php echo $contador3; ?></td>
                <td>
                  <?php echo $solicitud[1]; ?>&nbsp;

                  <button style="background:none; border:none; outline: none;" onclick="alertify.alert('Datos del Inmueble', '<?php echo $solicitud[4]; ?>', function(){ }).set('label', 'Aceptar').set('movable', false);" ><img height="25px" src="img/info-inmueble.png"/>
                  </button>&nbsp;

                  <a href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=<?php echo $solicitud[3];?>&z=15" target="_blank"><img height="25px" src="img/google-maps.png"/></a>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $solicitud[2]; ?></td>
                <td>
                  <button class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-ok" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Aceptar Inmueble" onclick="preguntarSiNo3('<?php echo $solicitud[0]; ?>')"></button>
                  <button class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Rechazar Inmueble" onclick="preguntarSiNo4('<?php echo $solicitud[0]; ?>')"></button>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <?php } ?>
            </tbody>

            <tfoot>
              <tr>
                <td></td> 
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

En mayo de 2017, Google lanzó la documentación oficial de URL de Google Maps. Las URL de Google Maps presentan una sintaxis universal multiplataforma que puede usar en sus aplicaciones.

Revisa esta documentación:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide

Puede usar las URL en los modos de búsqueda, indicaciones, mapa y vista de la calle. Y como ejemplo:

Para hacer lo que indicas, utiliza los siguientes parámetros:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=19.10711285128303,-98.27150480793455&zoom=20
" target="_blank">link</a>
```

Automaticamente se refactoriza la url por google maps

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ya lo intente y me sigue sin salir el marcador

Comment: Es raro, a mi me sale perfectamente. el pin, revisa si la consola te marca algo

Comment: no me sale nada en la consola, puse unas imagenes donde muestro donde esta mi link y como sale el mapa

Comment: Me puedes enseñar como colocas el html, lo que ocupas antes de...

Comment: El header? o que parte. Puse el código de todo lo que va antes del body

Comment: el HTML tal cual lo estas llamando donde pones el Link y por si las dudas, revisa la otra ventana donde mandes a llamar el mapa para ver que se esta pasando toda la url completa

Comment: ya puse el código, lo único que veo es que ya no le hace caso al zoom

Comment: Ya mostré el resultado, lo del zoom ya también lo modifiqué, abre una ventana de incognito, puede ser la caché

Comment: La respuesta está bien, pero el zoom no lo toma en cuenta. Puedes buscar lugares o coordenadas, pero eso sería todo